# Create Gradient Header in Image using C# Drawing Classes

Tags: c#, system.drawing, lineargradientbrush

I am trying to create an image in C# using the Drawing classes.  The image has a grid and I want to create a gradient header similar to this image.

[image]

Can I get some guidance on how to do this?  I tried using the LinearGradientBrush but I am struggling to get the same header look as it is in the image above.

Comment: You're likely to have more success if you create two gradients, one for the top and one for the bottom. You are trying to get a skeuomorphic effect that approximates a half-round header, you can't do that using a linear effect

Comment: For the top half, create a `LinearGradientBrush`, pass the **full bounds** and two semi-transparent white colors (A < 100). `.FillRectangle(x, y, width, height / 2);`.